# Ruby Gems "NameError: undefined local variable or method 'update' for main:Object" on every command

Tags: ruby, rubygems, watir

I'm attempting to set up a Watir environment.  I had several issues actually installing the gems necessary, so I uninstalled and reinstalled Ruby 1.9.3 (I'm running Windows 7.)  Now, I can't do any installs, updates, etc. from the ruby command line.  Here is an example of some simple commands that should work but are not:

```
C:\Users\Matt Adams>irb
irb(main):001:0> gem -v
NameError: undefined local variable or method `v' for main:Object
    from (irb):1
    from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0> gem update
NameError: undefined local variable or method `update' for main:Object
    from (irb):2
    from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

I can start ruby irb, but that's it.  Its almost as if none of the ruby commands were installed.  Anyone have any suggestions?  Note that I've already done a re-install.

Answer (score 0):

IRB is there for you to try out Ruby commands or snippets and see immediate responses. If you want to install or update gems, I suggest you get off IRB first by running "quit" and follow whatever instructions you have on your hand.